# Ant run command with pipes

Tags: java, ant

I must to implement command : `java -jar test.jar page.xml | mysql -u user -p base`
in ant. So i Have tried with this task:

```
<java jar="test.jar" fork="true">
  <arg line="page.xml | mysql -u user -p base"/>
</java>
```

But i have got en exception with pipe - "|" :

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input already set; can't set to |
```

So, that's the problem:)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The pipe (|) can only be used in a shell script. You're passing it as an argument to the java process.

So you need to execute a shell script. You can do this by executing (say) `bash -c` and passing the above as a shell statement (albeit *inline* - you could write a separate script file but it seems a bit of an overhead here)

```
  <exec executable="bash">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg line="java -jar test.jar page.xml | mysql -u user -p base"/>
  </exec>
```

Comment: wow, i just thought that it works, but not...
I have got:
No such file or directory

Comment: From what ? You may need to set your classpath (or similar - don't forget you're now spawning off a separate process)

Comment: Porblem was in <arg value="...">, it should be <arg line="...">
But now it writes: /usr/bin/java: /usr/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Yeah, <arg value="-b"/> doesn't work for me, but <arg value="-c"/> does. Of course, I'm executing a binary other than java, but still using the pipe.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if this was ever resolved, but I was having a similar problem which I solved by using the following:

```
<exec executable="bash">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg line='"java -jar test.jar page.xml | mysql -u user -p base"'/>
</exec>
```

Just thought I would share.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to wrap the `java -jar test.jar page.xml | mysql -u user -p base` into a separate script and call it with simple `<exec>` task.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a java program from Ant, the input and out from the program are captured by the Ant runtime - you can't try and redirect them elsewhere using that pipe.

If you want to do that, you might have better luck with the `exec` task, although that might suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There you are actually running a java command.

You need to use Exec task http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html but not sure if there also you can run piped commands or not. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining why Amelie's answer is the correct solution:

The difference between Amelie's correct solution compared to Brain Agnew's solution is the subtle difference between them.  Brian had the second arg as a "value" while Amelie is using "line".

Here's why Amelie's is correct, per [Apache Ant Documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg):

- "value | a single command-line argument; can contain space characters."
- "line | a space-delimited list of command-line arguments."

```html
<exec executable="bash">
    <arg value="-c"/>
    <arg line='"java -jar test.jar page.xml | mysql -u user -p base"'/>
</exec>
```