# Ant apply fileset and file as command input

Tags: mysql, ant

I will use the following command to import a set of sql files using the mysql commnd.

```
<apply dir="${basedir}" executable="mysql" failonerror="true" parallel="true">
    <arg value="-u${db.main.user}" />
    <arg value="-p${db.main.password}" />
    <arg value="-P${db.main.port}" />
    <arg value="-h${db.main.host}" />
    <arg value="-D${db.main.database}" />
    <srcfile/>

    <fileset dir="${db.main.path_to_dump}">
        <filename name="keyword_category_rel.sql"/>
        <filename name="keyword_classification.sql"/>
    </fileset>
 </apply>
```

The problem is that the mysql command execept the file as command input not as a parameter. So is there a way to provide the file from the fileset as input not as parameter?

Another option is to use the -e argument it accept the sql code from the file, but how can i read the data from the file of the fileset list into a property?

Answer (score 4):

To pass the content of each 'iterator' file in an `apply` task you can use an input [redirector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/redirector.html).  For example:

```
<apply executable="${mysql}" addsourcefile="false">
    <fileset dir="${sql.dir}" />
    <redirector>
      <inputmapper type="glob" from="*" to="${sql.dir}/*" />
    </redirector>
</apply>
```

will process each file found under the `sql.dir` as the input stream of a `mysql` invocation.
I've omitted all the mysql credential args; they would be needed.

In your example you specify two `filename` elements for the fileset, but neither contains any wildcard - note that in the [`fileset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) docs it says:

> If any of the selectors within the FileSet do not select the file, the
>   file is not considered part of the FileSet. This makes a FileSet
>   equivalent to an `<and>` selector container.

So your example fileset will actually match *zero* files.

You might also look into using the Ant [`sql` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Another user asked about [Ant run command with pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1187402/127035) for the same reason. Maybe the solutions there will solve your problem.

Comment: my problem is that i will use the fileset. the problem is that i can't access the srcfile property so i can't use the bash execution

Answer (score 0):

Try the exec task combined with a for loop provided by **[Ant addon Flaka](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)** like that :

```
<project name="demo" xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">

 <!-- define your fileset -->
 <fileset dir="${db.main.path_to_dump}" id="foobar">
  <filename name="keyword_category_rel.sql"/>
  <filename name="keyword_classification.sql"/>
 </fileset>

 <!-- call exec for every file in your fileset -->
 <fl:for var="file" in="split('${toString:foobar}', ';')">
  <exec executable="mysql" dir="${basedir}/${build}" input="#{file}">
   <arg value="-u${db.main.user}"/>
   <arg value="-p${db.main.password}"/>
   <arg value="-P${db.main.port}"/>
   <arg value="-h${db.main.host}"/>
   <arg value="-D${db.main.database}"/>
  </exec>
 </fl:for>

</project>
```