# xcodebuild print errors only

Tags: ant, xcodebuild

I saw this command in SO [How to filter the xcodebuild command line output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244637/how-to-filter-the-xcodebuild-command-line-output)

which shows only the errors and warnings when we do xcodebuild otherwise the xcodebuild commands prints everything to the console regarding what it is doing.

Is there a way I can use grep with xcodebuild in an ant task ?

```
 <exec executable="xcodebuild" failonerror="true">
                <arg value="| grep error" />
                <arg value="clean" />
                <arg value="build" />
  </exec>
```

The exec task above throws error while trying to execute the ant task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187402/ant-run-command-with-pipes) question might be helpful. I also suppose you need to invoke actions first and then grep. Maybe this will work:

```
<exec dir="${projectPath}/" executable="bash" failonerror="true">
   <arg value="-c"/>
   <arg value="xcodebuild clean build | grep error"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: yes thanks that seems to work.. however had to add the dir for the exec                 <exec dir="${projectPath}/" executable="bash" failonerror="true">

Answer (score 7):

-quiet                                                   do not print any output except for warnings and errors

```
xcodebuild clean build -quiet
```

it works.